# Prove that if $a_n<b_n<c_n$ and $\sum a_n$ and $\sum c_n$ are convrgent then $\sum b_n $ converge

Tags: calculus, analysis

First of all argument bounded and monotone will not work because there is no restriction on sequences to be positive or negative, they can alternate irregularly.

I tried to make a use of comparison test but there was too many cases to consider and it was just too messy.

So I think the only way to approach the problem is directly from the definition. All I need to do is to prove that the sequence of partial sums $B_n=\sum^n_{i=0} b_i$ is convergent sequence.  So I tried to prove that $B_n$  is Cauchy because this seemed easier.
$$a_n<b_n<c_n
\\ \therefore \ a_n+a_{n+1}+...+a_{n+m}<b_n+b_{n+1}+...+b_{n+m}<c_n+c_{n+1}+...+c_{n+m}\\ \therefore  \ A_{n+m}-A_n<B_{n+m}-B_n<C_{n+m}-C_n$$ and by sandwich this goes to zero $B_{n+m}-B_n$ goes to zero as $n$ tend to infinity. The problem is that I need no this expressions but modulus of them and in this case it does not need to be true for example if  $A_{n+m}-A_n<0<B_{n+m}-B_n$. And here I am stuck

Comment: Do $\sum a_n$ and  $\sum c_n$ converge to the same limit?

Comment: Perhaps consider $0 < b_n - a_n < c_n -a_n$.

Answer (score 3):

The partial sums form a Cauchy sequence: If $n<m$ then $$\sum_{j=n}^m a_j < \sum_{j=n}^m b_j<\sum_{j=n}^m c_j.$$Since $\sum_{j=n}^m a_j\to0$ and $\sum_{j=n}^m c_j\to0$ as $n,m\to\infty$ it follows that $\sum_{j=n}^m b_j\to0$, qed.